# subtraction similar to sum()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have function, which must add entry to database, depending on variable's content:

```
def n_insert(self, optype, opsum, avail):

    self.optype = optype
    self.opsum = opsum
    self.avail = avail

    if self.optype == 'in':
        print('IN')
        print(self.avail)
        new = sum(self.avail, opsum)
        print(new)
    else:
        print('OUT')
        print(self.avail)
```

If `self.optype == 'OUT'` - it must do something like:

```
 new = subtraction(self.avail, opsum)
```

But -  I can't google something like this... `sum()` is - so is there like `subtraction()` method?

Sure, it can be done with simple `-` operator, but...

Comment: `sum()` adds all the elements of a sequence. What would `subtraction()` do?

Comment: reduce https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: What types are `self.avail` and `self.opsum`?

Answer (score 4):

Substracting all elements is only `-sum(l)`:

```
>>> l = range(1,10)
>>> sum(l)
45
>>> -sum(l)
-45
```

If you want to substact all the elements from the first:

```
>>> l[1:]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l[0]-sum(l[1:])
-43
```

Comment: What if you have a very large positive number and you subtract a smaller one. The result would still be positive ...